# Regex Only words and single spaces between them

Tags: regex, dart

I'm not good with writing regex. The requirement is to validate names.

- Only letters should include
- Only 1 space between the words
- Cannot include any other space characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```js
^[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/GOAo14/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                           (1 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```